# how do I write a golang multiple interacting particle system?

Tags: go, concurrency, particles

I want to have a collection of objects, each of which depend on all or some of the others.
I plan on having two concurrency groups where in the first,
each object calculates the radius to all the others,
then retrieves the charge of each other and calculates the force and stores the force.
In the second concurrency group, each object moves its (x,y,z) in proportion to the force.
So, by switching back and forth between concurrency groups,
objects move without race conditions.
I want the system to run continuously until a keyboard quit request.
I've done a fair amount of searching without finding a foothold.
Please recommend a link, or show a very simple example of querying independent others.
I appreciate that I should offer a MWE, but I am an absolute golang beginner
with a fair number of chops in C++, Python, javascript, LISP, FORTRAN, and many others.
I don't know where to start.  I've looked at functions, objects, etc... without insight.
Please help.

Comment: Sounds like, at top level, you want a loop that alternately calls one function to update the forces acting on each "particle," and then another function to update the positions of each particle. Now, your question becomes: What's the most efficient way for a golang function to cause each member of a list of objects to be updated in some way, and not return until the job is done?  (I'm not a golang person so, sorry, but I don't know the answer.)

Comment: The way I see it, you'll be working with pairs: calculate the distance and force between each. You can partition the list of pairs, and give each to a goroutine to do the calculation. Goroutines are not preemptible (yet), so you will get groups of goroutines running in parallel based on the number of cores you have. If you have 1, it'll be all sequential.  You can do the same for the second part. Also, you can start working on the second phase of an object once all pairs containing it are done.

Comment: What I want is for each object to specifically query the (x,y,z) from each object from its list of known objects.  In other words, each object is responsible for its own force calculation, and does so by asking all the other objects it knows.  My goal is not electrostatics but connected graphs in 3 space.